# How to Access WorkPlanes of Occurrences in Assemblies using the Inventor API with Python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, autodesk-inventor

I want to add constraints between the planes of the base-coordinate systems of components in an Inventor assmbly using the Inventor API with Python. The placement of the components works. My issue is, that i cannot access WorkPlanes in the Definition of my individual Occurrences.
My Code looks like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
project_folder = "C:\\Users\\User_1\\210608_project\\"

#initialization
inv = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Inventor.Application')
inv.Visible = True

#Open a new assembly
inv.Documents.Add(win32.constants.kAssemblyDocumentObject, "", True)
invActDoc = inv.ActiveDocument
invAssDoc = win32.CastTo(invActDoc, 'AssemblyDocument')


#Create the transient matrices
oTG = inv.TransientGeometry
oMatrix = oTG.CreateMatrix()

#Add component to assembly
invAssDocDef = invAssDoc.ComponentDefinition
invAssOcc = invAssDocDef.Occurrences
occ1 = invAssOcc.Add(project_folder + 'generic_part_1.ipt', oMatrix)
occ2 = invAssOcc.Add(project_folder + 'generic_part_2.ipt', oMatrix)


#create constraints
#get the Planes of the Base-Coordinate-System of Part 1
wp_YZ_1 = occ1.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(1)
wp_XZ_1 = occ1.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(2)
wp_XY_1 = occ1.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(3)

#get the Planes of the Base-Coordinate-System of Part 2
wp_YZ_2 = occ2.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(1)
wp_XZ_2 = occ2.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(2)
wp_XY_2 = occ2.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(3)

#Add the constraints
AssCons = invAssDoc.ComponentDefinition.Constraints
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_YZ_1, wp_YZ_2, 0)
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_XZ_1, wp_XZ_2, 0)
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_XY_1, wp_XY_2, 0)
```

It breaks when i try to get the WorkPlanes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/210608_projekt/how_to_constrain_components_in_assemblies.py", line 27, in <module>
    wp1 = occ1.Definition.WorkPlanes.Item(1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.ComponentDefinition instance at 0x2748634277928>' object has no attribute 'WorkPlanes'
```

This happens to everything that I tried, that is inside of Occurrence.Item(i).Definition.

If i open the same assembly in a VBA script, everything is where it should be. Am I missing something about working with occurrences using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `WorkPlaneProxy` object of the `WorkPlane`. It means representation of workplane defined in part in context of specific occurrence in the assembly

Here is part of VB.NET code

```vb
'Define variables for workplane proxy
Dim wp_YZ_1_proxy As WorkPlaneProxy
Dim wp_YZ_2_proxy As WorkPlaneProxy

'You need to pass result variable as argument
' ByRef in VB.NET, out in C#
'I don't know how to do in Python 
occ1.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_YZ_1, wp_YZ_1_proxy)
occ2.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_YZ_2, wp_YZ_2_proxy)

Dim AssCons As AssemblyConstraints = asm.Constraints

'Use this proxies for constraint creation
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_YZ_1_proxy, wp_YZ_2_proxy, 0)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I think you are right in regards to the usage in AddFlushConstraint. My Issue is that i can't get the WorkPlane in the first place, so i can't create a proxy for it (object has no attribute 'WorkPlanes').

Comment: OK, you need to cast ```occ.Definition``` to ```PartComponentDefinition``` or ```AssemblyComponentDefinition```. Both is derived from basic ```ComponentDefinition```, and both has ```WorkPlanes``` property.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how the solution/replacement of the last 3 blocks looks like:

```
#cast the definitions to PartComponentDefinition
occ1_def = win32.CastTo(occ1.Definition, 'PartComponentDefinition')
occ2_def = win32.CastTo(occ2.Definition, 'PartComponentDefinition')

#create constraints
#get the Planes of the Base-Coordinate-System of Part 1
wp_YZ_1 = occ1_def.WorkPlanes.Item(1)
wp_XZ_1 = occ1_def.WorkPlanes.Item(2)
wp_XY_1 = occ1_def.WorkPlanes.Item(3)

#create Geometry-Proxys for Workplanes of Comp1
wp_YZ_1_proxy = occ1.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_YZ_1)
wp_XZ_1_proxy = occ1.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_XZ_1)
wp_XY_1_proxy = occ1.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_XY_1)


#get the Planes of the Base-Coordinate-System of Part 2
wp_YZ_2 = occ2_def.WorkPlanes.Item(1)
wp_XZ_2 = occ2_def.WorkPlanes.Item(2)
wp_XY_2 = occ2_def.WorkPlanes.Item(3)

#create Geometry-Proxys for Workplanes of Comp2
wp_YZ_2_proxy = occ2.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_YZ_2)
wp_XZ_2_proxy = occ2.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_XZ_2)
wp_XY_2_proxy = occ2.CreateGeometryProxy(wp_XY_2)

#Add the constraints
AssCons = invAssDoc.ComponentDefinition.Constraints
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_YZ_1_proxy, wp_YZ_2_proxy, 0)
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_XZ_1_proxy, wp_XZ_2_proxy, 0)
AssCons.AddFlushConstraint(wp_XY_1_proxy, wp_XY_2_proxy, 0)
```